# Issues with asp.net and matlab runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, matlab-deployment

I have very strange problem.

I have programmed some function in matlab and deployed it with Matlab Builder NE as dll file. Next I've added reference to this module into my asp.net application. When I display the web page in browser on localhost (mean visual studio development server), the function gives me the numbers I need. However, when I display the web page from remote computer, I get this error :

```
Exception: System.TypeInitializationException

Message: The type initializer for 'Module.Func' threw an exception.

StackTrace:    at Module.Func.Finalize()

InnerException: System.Exception

Message: The MCR instance could not be initialized
```

I am running IIS 6 and it also throws exception in w3wp.exe. I have no idea, where is the problem, because on localhost it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find an answer here (this is Matlab thread about the similar errors).
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/171699

The forum post mentions missing dependencies and/or timeouts.

In general if you deploy your solution to another machine you need to make sure that you deployed all dependencies. Also there might be a differeces in environmental settings that you need to account for (debug=true vs. debug=false, timeouts etc..).